# memoir page layout for playing card

Tags: memoir

I'm building fraction cards, This is (approximately) what they will look like. The final size should be  2.5" x 3.5", the fraction text centered horizontally and appropriately positioned vertically and the hawk logo lower right.

[image]

The hacked up MWE below uses the `memoir` class to get the large old style numbers, so I can't (or shouldn't) use `geometry` to get the page layout right. I've looked at related questions, played a lot with the `memoir` stock size and layout directives and struggled with the manual pages, to no avail. So it's time to ask here: how do I set the stock size to 2.5x3.5, then set margins? Spline should be 0 and recto/verso irrelevant.

Perhaps the logo should be in a footer.

If this is an x-y problem and I should be using `tikz` from the start I'm open to that.

Second question, which I can ask separately if necessary: the fraction bar doesn't seem to be centered.

Design suggestions also welcome.

(I know how to automate the task of producing the deck I want.)

```
\documentclass[extrafontsizes,60pt,showtrims]{memoir}
\usepackage[fulloldstylenums]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%\setstocksize{3.5in}{2.5in}
\setstocksize{5in}{4in}
\settypeblocksize{3.5in}{2.5in}{*}

%\setlrmarginsandblock{0in}{0in}{*}
%\setpagecc{3.5in}{2.5in}{*}

\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\num}{3}
\newcommand{\den}{5}
\newcommand{\fractionbar}{%
\vspace{-0.6in}
\rule{1.2in}{3.5pt}
\vspace{-0.5in}
}
\begin{document}
%\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{center}
\num\\
\fractionbar\\
\den
\end{center}
\vspace{-1.1in}
\par
\hspace{0.4in}
\includegraphics[width=0.5in]{heath-logo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So each document will provide you with one card... and then you'll probably have that as an image you can import somewhere else?

Comment: @Werner Yes, one card per document (or perhaps pdf page) depending on what the print-on-demand company wants. I can handle that part. No recto/verso pages, of course.

Comment: What's the first question?

Comment: @cfr The first question is "how do I set the stock size to 2.5x3.5, then set margins?". Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Why can't you do that? You've commented out the lines which would do that and set the type block to those dimensions instead. Why?

Comment: @cfr All the combinations of comment/uncomment I've tried lead to various kinds of errors or misplacements. I thought it better to ask for a solution from scratch rather than post the problem from some particular faulty combination.

Comment: So what page size? If the stock size is 2.5 by 3.5 inches, then you need to also say what the page size is and what size the type block should be.

Comment: Memoir just isn't meant for this. Really, it is nothing but class abuse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a template you could consider following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=0pt,papersize={2.5in,3.5in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[fulloldstylenums]{kpfonts}

% To aid in visual positioning (remove/comment in final version)
\usepackage[gridunit=in,grid=true]{eso-pic}

\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\numerator}{12345}
\newcommand{\denominator}{67890}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\setlength{\unitlength}{1in}%
\begin{picture}(2.5,3.5)
  % Numerator above rule
%  \put(0,1.75) {\raisebox{\dimexpr0.5in+-1.75pt+.5\height}{\makebox[2.5in]{\scalebox{8}{\numerator}}}}
  \put(0,2.2){\makebox[2.5in]{\raisebox{1.75pt}{\scalebox{8}{\numerator}}}}
  % Rule exactly in middle of card
  \put(0,1.75){\makebox[2.5in]{\rule[-1.75pt]{1.2in}{3.5pt}}}
  % Denominator below rule
  \put(0,1.7){\raisebox{\dimexpr-1.75pt-\height}{\makebox[2.5in]{\scalebox{8}{\denominator}}}}
  % Image in lower-right corner (0.2in from bottom, 0.2in from right)
  \put(0,0.2) {\makebox[2.5in][r]{\includegraphics[width=0.5in]{example-image}\hspace{0.2in}}}
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

For completeness, I've added a grid (using [`eso-pic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) to help you with the positioning. Additionally, I've included all numbers in the `\numerator` and `\denominator` so you can see the vertical distribution. Besides that the placement of content uses a `picture` environment, measuring in `in`ches.

Due to using oldstyle numbers, the placement may be problematic as some numbers have visually different ascenders/descenders.

Comment: +1 Thank you. Nice to wake up in the morning with two solutions to choose between. I'll accept one when I decide which to use. I may indeed have to abandon the oldstyle numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a different take on Werner's answer. (Werner answered while I was writing, else I would not have bothered to write it.)

This uses `geometry` and `article` but `tikz` is used for placement of the logo. This is clearly overkill, but works. Werner's answer is more sophisticated than this code and I post this merely as a curiosity and not because I recommend it given that alternative.

Still, that said, mine does have a cat, so it is at least more godlike in one respect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fulloldstylenums]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=2.5in,paperheight=3.5in,hscale=1,vscale=.5,vmarginratio=6:5,marginparwidth=0pt,marginparsep=0pt,footskip=0pt,headheight=0pt,headsep=0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand{\num}{3}
\newcommand{\den}{5}
\newcommand{\fractionbar}{%
  \vspace{-0.6in}%
  \rule{1.2in}{3.5pt}%
  \vspace{-0.5in}%
}
\begin{document}
  \fontsize{60}{70}\selectfont
  \begin{center}
    \num\\
    \fractionbar\\
    \den
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{%
      \node [anchor=north east] at (current page.east) {\includegraphics[width=0.5in]{cath}};
    }%
  \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: cat pack]

Comment: Very very nice, excellent your work.

Comment: +1 Thank you. Nice to wake up in the morning with two solutions to choose between. I'll accept one when I decide which to use.